# Can I change the options of an individual vertex in \Vertices?

Tags: tkz-graph

Consider the following code that produces vertices on a line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {minimum size = 8pt, inner sep = 0pt}}     

% Lpos=90 now affects every vertex in this "set"!
\Vertices[Lpos=90,unit=2]{line}{a,b,c,d,e,f}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

By adding things like `Lpos=90` as an option to `\Vertices`, I can affect the style of each vertex in the "set" that happens to be a `line`. However, is it possible to set options for individual options in a "set"? For example, could I pass in some options to only have a label visible for say the vertices b and e?

**Motivation:** I already have a picture using a `line`, and other vertices that depend on the vertices in it. However, I realized some vertices on the `line` need a label. I'd like to avoid removing the `\Vertices` command and drawing each vertex on the line as an individual vertex.